# read package.json from the code : package.json.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript, package.json

I have an angular application but when I try this code :

```
require("../../../package.json").version
```

I get this error message :`Error loading http://localhost/package.json.js as "../../../package.json" from app.component.js`

why am i getting : package.json.js file? with such bizzare extension?

Thanks,

Comment: That's not going to happen since whatever is bundling your application is "correctly" not starting from the project root, but is rather working from the "source root". You really should not be doing this anyway. If for some reason you really convince yourself you do need the file, then part of your build should copy this to a deployable assets location.

Comment: what is the best way to handle this ? I would like to read the application name and the version from package.json.

Comment: As already mentioned that's really not a good idea. How is the application being built?

Comment: i use npm run and the app is using systemjs

Comment: I am using gulp