# "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically" when importing JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, module, angular-cli

I have an application in Angular 4 and I want to display version of my application somewhere in the view. The version string is expectedly contained in `package.json` `version` property.

What I've tried is to create a class and import JSON file directly into it, then expose the variable through getter method:

```typescript
import * as PACKAGE from './../../../package.json';

export class PackageService {

  public static getVersion (): string {
    return (PACKAGE as any).version;
  }

}
```

However, this solution raises compilation problems such as this one:

`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 8:13 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol PackageService.getVersion in ./src/app/services/package.service.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in ./src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in ./src/app/app.module.ts`

`webpack: Failed to compile.`

Looks like the problem is with method being static. When I convert this class to normal Angular injectable service. It compiles correctly.

I'm using static method in order to add version string to DI container with: `{provide: DI_VERSION, useValue: PackageService.getVersion()}`, where `DI_VERSION` is an injection token. This would allow me to access the version string directly without injecting entire service and calling methods on it.

What exactly is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'll say the same thing I said earlier on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084857/read-package-json-from-the-code-package-json-js-404-not-found. It's a very bad idea to do this. For one, the `package.json` file is in the "project root" and your application sits under `/src` here. So it's basically bad practice to try and refer to anything outside of that tree structure  (node_modules dependencies excepted). If you really think you need this then get the build process to copy to an accessible location.

Comment: Also 2 people asking the same thing in such a short period? Is there some tutorial posted somewhere where you are reading this evaluate content from `package.json`?

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please either write an answer (if you think it would be useful to others) or delete the question,

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for your answer, but I've never asked you to edit my question and to remove valuable information from it.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for a suggestion. Is there another way to inject version number to Angular application? I'm using Angular CLI and I can't really affect the building pipeline. Also, why accessing the `package.json` is considered a bad practice, is there some real practical drawbacks?

Comment: Well you could always use `ng eject` and that will give your project a `webpack.config.js` to play with and add plugins. As for practical drawbacks, you just ran into one and asked this question. It's bad practice. Application source lives in source and anything else confuses matters.

Comment: @NeilLunn I will look into `ng eject`, thanks. Actually, my problem is not with location of the JSON file, but with accessing it. It doesn't really matter if it's inside `./src/` or not for this issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The purpose of my update is to show that this error is caused by method being static. I don't know the source of the problem yet, and I'm still interesting to make my example work or to understand why it's not working or why I shouldn't do it this way. What if I don't want to make this class an injectable service?

Comment: Then by all means explain *why* you want to make a "service" that's not actually a service.

Comment: I'm with @jonrsharpe on that point. I'm also wondering if your choice of `static` was under the presumption that otherwise this would be creating instances and copying the `package.json` data around? So explaining your intent would go a long way here.

Comment: Sorry for being vague here, your are right. I've updated my question to make it more straightforward. Thank you for all the suggestions, the `ng inject` is actually looks pretty cool.